# IOS/Objective-C: Filter array of events with NSPredicate to find Dates close to now

Tags: ios, nsdate, nspredicate

I fetch an array of events from Core Data. In turn, I want to filter the results to obtain any events currently taking place, ie that started within the last hour.

I'm a bit fuzzy on how to filter the array and even fuzzier on how to work with dates in an NSpredicate. I think I need to calculate a time that is one hour before the present, a second that is a short time from the futrue, and then compare these the starttime but I'm not sure how to go about it.

This is what I have so far:

```
//fetch from coredata
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                       error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *mutableresults = [results mutableCopy];
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval backSecondsInHour = -60 * 60;
    NSTimeInterval forwardSecondsInHour = 60 * 60;

    NSDate* hourAgo =  [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:backSecondsInHour sinceDate:now];
    NSDate* hourFromNow =  [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:forwardSecondsInHour sinceDate:now];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"starttime >= %@&&starttime<=%@",hourAgo,hourFromNow];
    NSArray *filteredEvents=[mutableresults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Am I on the right track here?  Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead retrieving all events every time from database just fetch only needed events...

Here is example if predicate applied to fetchRequest for all events since last hour:

```
NSDate *hourAgo = [[Date date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-3600];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = .....
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"starttime >= %@", hourAgo];
```